# WSO2 revoke api

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I was curious how can see the revoke api end point exists.The url configured is 
https://localhost:9443/revoke
But I could see the api listed under the started application or under api.
I even tried retrieving the wadl from the url but it did not return anything.
Do we need to explicitly publish it or it gets done automatically when we start the wso2server ? Or Do we need to install something other than the wso2 api manager to get this api?
When I browse the endpoint https://localhost:9443/revoke/?_wadl , I get error 
 405 - method not allowed

Answer (score 0):

The port should be 8243.

And it's not a SOAP service.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Token+API#TokenAPI-Revokingaccesstokens